# Adjective that relates to 'hair'

Tags: word-request

Is there an adjective that relates to 'hair'?
We have adjectives for other parts of body like *oral* for mouth, *corporal* for body, *dental* for teeth etc.

For example, for the disorder of mouth, we'd say *oral disorder*. For the disorder of *hair*, **"(?) disorder"** (other than 'hair disorder').

Does English have an adjective for 'hair'?

Comment: https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-adjective-for/hair.html

Comment: In a medical context, we might use the prefix 'tricho-', as in "trichosis", a general term for any disorder of the hair.

Comment: Hair is not living, so it can't be disordered. You can have a "follicular disorder," which is a disorder of the live [hair follicle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hair%20follicle) that grows the hair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The word you seek is *pilar*.**

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pilar) defines the word *pilar* to mean:

> of or relating to the hair or a hair

Another seemingly less common term is [*crinal*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crinal):

> of or relating to the hair

I say "less common" having observed the following Ngram:

[image]

Interestingly, there may be a slight difference in meaning between the two, indicated in the pages of James Cowles Prichard's [*Researches Into the Physical History of Mankind, Volume 1*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=i9hSAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA239&dq=%22crinal%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjG-bTfk93rAhUnnOAKHZE9D5IQ6AEwAnoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22crinal%22&f=false):

> For the sake of facilitating comparison, I shall divide the hair into crinal and pilar, terming crinal that of the head, beard, &c., and pilar that which grows upon the trunk, particularly on the breast and on the limbs.

As pointed out in the [comments](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/259760/adjective-that-relates-to-hair#comment487082_259760), however, hair itself cannot suffer from a disorder as it is not living.

**Yes, English has at least two adjectives for *hair*, and they are *pilar* and *crinal*.**

*P.S. I used the [Reverse Dictionary](https://reversedictionary.org/wordsfor/relating%20to%20hair) to find these terms. You might find it helpful in future.*

Comment: Great find, but it should be pointed out that these are technical terms the average person wouldn’t know.

Comment: @StephenS Indeed, they could be considered medical jargon. I couldn't find a more common term unfortunately, except for maybe the phrase "of hair", if that counts.